# Cannot find pygraphviz

Tags: python, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, python-3.5, pygraphviz

I am trying to install pygraphviz and get it linked to my python3 installation.

`pip3 list` shows a list which does not contain `pygraphviz`

```
sudo apt install python-pydot python-pydot-ng graphviz
```

will run and install but not help matters.

`pip3 install pygraphviz` results in

Failed building wheel for pygraphviz

`sudo pip3 install pygraphviz` results in

> Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pygraphviz
>   in /home/computer1/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages

Comment: you must have multiple versions of python- what does `which python3` show?

Comment: @Chris_Rands it just shows /usr/bin/python3

Answer (score 2):

If i remember well, on Windows, in order to use pygraphviz in Python, you need to install Graphviz Tool and add Graphviz installation path (like bin folder) in PATH Variable.

See : http://www.graphviz.org/

I think it should be the same on Linux.
Try to run an installation command like `apt-get install -y graphviz-dev` and then try to install pygraphviz with pip install.

Comment: thanks for the response. I tried this, problem still persists unfortunately :(

Comment: We can try to just reinstall all, like install first Graphviz Tool and after Python. I have done it some months ago with a virtualenv: just recreating it, i was able to install the library.

Answer (score 0):

Some or all of your issue may be related to versioning. Your post is tagged with python-3.5, but your apt command shows you install python-2 packages. If you want to install pydot and pydot-ng with apt for python-3.5, then the command should be

```
apt install python3-pydot python3-pydot-ng
```

I have had mostly bad experiences using pip to install/upgrade Python packages for Ubuntu's distribution of Python. I do not generally recommend it. To that end, there is a way to install pygraphviz via apt.

```
apt install python3-pygraphviz
```

Installing via apt is advantageous because you don't have to deal with the overhead of building the wheels.